# Fast Fourier Transform in Python?

Tags: python, signal-processing, fft, continuous-fourier

I have this dataset with oscillations:

```
y = array([ 9.88706879e-05, -1.80853647e-05,  2.42572582e-05, 
1.12215205e-04,
        1.32105126e-04,  1.13424614e-05, -1.58262175e-04, -2.62013276e-04,
       -2.58070932e-04, -1.53975865e-04, -8.19357356e-05, -1.55734157e-04,
       -2.90791620e-04, -3.70294471e-04, -3.46855608e-04, -2.23495910e-04,
       -1.35441615e-04, -2.11411786e-04, -4.21891416e-04, -6.77753516e-04,
       -8.09657243e-04, -6.97948704e-04, -5.01935670e-04, -4.20075723e-04,
       -5.28464040e-04, -8.14942203e-04, -1.03669983e-03, -9.76604755e-04,
       -7.50889655e-04, -5.34882634e-04, -4.06928662e-04, -3.96093220e-04,
       -4.31306957e-04, -4.25399844e-04, -3.26933980e-04, -1.32440493e-04,
        5.40550849e-06, -4.87299567e-05, -2.04672372e-04, -3.15870097e-04])

x = array([-25, -20, -15, -10,  -5,   0,   5,  10,  15,  20,  25,  30, 35,
        40,  45,  50,  55,  60,  65,  70,  75,  80,  85,  90,  95, 100,
       105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140, 145, 150, 155, 160, 165,
       170])
```

How can I measure the Fast Fourier Transform in Python?

That is how my data look: [image]

and this is the output of the FFT:

```
N = np.shape(x)
T = (200/N)*10e-12 #time step in sec
xf = fftfreq(N,1/T)[:N//2]
yf = fft(y)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(xf, 2.0/N*np.abs(yf[0:N//2]))
plt.xlabel('freq.(Hz)')
plt.ylabel('f(t)')
```

[image]

I am wondering if the script is correct.

Comment: Do you mean *compute* ? https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html

Comment: In addition to numpy, you can also use scipy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/fft.html

Comment: Putting just your question title into a search engine would have quickly lead you to various relevant results. Have you tried that?

Comment: @9769953 I tried, but since I am new with Python I am wondering if it's correct the script I wrote.

Comment: That's quite a different question what you have now from what you started with.

Comment: Why the factor 10e-12 (i.e., 1e-11)? Note that values on the x-axis of your FFT. What is the timescale of your data? -25 to +75 *what*?

Comment: @9769953 since the time range (-25 to 170) is in ps, I converted in seconds with a factor 10e-12 ...

Comment: ps for picoseconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two practical mistakes in your original code:

- `10e-12` is not 10^-12; it's 10^-11. Use `1e-12` for 10^-12
- `N = np.shape(x)` results in `N` being a tuple, which shouldn't work in the other parts of the code. So the given code fails with a `TypeError`.

But that won't fix your problem. I'm not too familiar with FFTs, but simplifying your code a bit, combined with some intuition (which might be incorrect), I can get the following with seemingly correct results:

```
N = len(x)
dt = 5e-12
xf = fftfreq(N, dt)[:N//2]
yf = fft(y)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf)[0:N//2])
plt.xlabel('freq.(Hz)')
plt.ylabel('f(t)')
```

(The "magic" `5e-12` can be obtained in numerous ways. One way is `dt = (x[1] - x[0]) * 1e-12`, assuming equal spacing for `x` (which it should have anyway) and converting to seconds.)

That yields the image below. There is a small peak around 3e10 Hz, which equals a period of about 1 / 3e10 = 3.3e-11 seconds or 33 picoseconds. Which seems about right, looking at the x-y data graph in your question.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your answer solved my problem. Now, I can see the peak corresponding to the ~30picosec period!